Pyuic5 generating file with syntax errors
Using Qt designer in order to create .ui file and then using pyuic5 to translate it to .py format yields file riddled with syntax errors because of "::" syntax.
Command used:
pyuic5 -x MainMenu.ui -o MainMenu.py
Fragment of MainMenu.py for example:
self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtCore.Qt.QLayout::SizeConstraint::SetNoConstraint)

This is obviously not Python syntax (atleast none that I know of) and looks more like c++.
Error message (first that pops up):
self.labelTitle.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.Qt::TextFormat::AutoText) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Obviously the file will not compile. Changing some of the "::" into "." gets rid of some of those erros, but considering that this is persistant with each file generation I would like to get to the root of problem.

This shouldn't happen. What version of PyQt? How did you install Designer? Do you also have Qt6 (possibly PyQt or PySide) installed as well? Can you provide the UI file?

@musicamante Im sorry for wasting your time, I have upgraded from PyQt5 to PyQt6 and there does not seem to be such a problem there. Still curious, as what has caused that.

Without knowing more about your previous environment (see the above questions, but other information may be required) we cannot really tell you more about that issue.

Post a [mre] including a sample ui file.

If anyone is having the same issue, make sure not to just open the ui file in QtCreator. Open the folder containing the file as a workspace such that QtCreator can configure the project as a Qt 5.xx project. After that, pyuic5 should work as expected.
